# Mirror API Quickstart PHP - Reply Notification Subscription?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

How do you send and process REPLY actions using the PHP SDK?

I've tried modifying these two files in the quckstart:

1) index.php in `case 'insertItemWithAction':`

```
$menu_item = new Google_MenuItem();
$menu_item->setAction("REPLY");
array_push($menu_items, $menu_item);
```

2) notify.php with a conditional (in the main `case 'timeline'`) to try to get the reply processed:

`else if($user_action['type'] == 'REPLY') ...`

However, it seems the reply isn't processed - or am I missing a parameter somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are only sent to your Glassware only if the user is subscribed to notifications. With the Quick Start project, you can verify this by going to the main page and see if the "Subscriptions" section reads "Unsubscribe from timeline updates".

Also, notification only works for deployed Glassware as the endpoint needs to be publicly accessible and encrypted (`https`).

Comment: I'm definitely subscribed + I'm using the supplied proxy for https (for dev testing)... but, I'm still not receiving the added lines from REPLY

Comment: Does it work when sharing a picture? Could you add some logging on your notification endpoint to get more information?